# strncpy adding extra characters to my char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a character array of words. Some of them surrounded by *. If one is found, I want it put into my buffer array. I looked at test[i] + 1 in my watch window, and it does what I want. It reads as "example*". I figured if I used strncpy to copy this over with two less characters than the size of it, I would get "example", but instead, I'm getting things like "examples." or "examplers.", which doesn't make any sense to me.

```
char ** test;
char * buffer;
int elemLen;
if (*test[i] == '*')
{
    elemLen = strlen(test[i]);
    strncpy(buffer, test[i] + 1, elemLen - 2);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your strings are terminated with `'\0'`.

Comment: Is that all the code? `buffer` is uninitialized, pointing somewhere unknown, and you're copying chunks of text into it. "Weird extra characters" is the *least* bad consequence I can think of.

Comment: `buffer` is an uninitialized pointer and `strncpy` does not null terminate the string if the string is longer than the buffer size.

Comment: Thank you guys. I see my problem now. Buffer has extra characters from when I used it previously. I need a null character at the end of my string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must manually add a null character as strncopy will not do it for you.

i.e.

```
elemLen = strlen(test[i]);
strncpy(buffer, test[i] + 1, elemLen - 2);
buffer[elemLen - 2] = '\0';
```

Comment: I just noticed that right before you answered. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelBlake Please accept answer if you've got this solved =)

Comment: should be `buffer[elemLen - 2] = '\0';`  , arrays are zero-indexed so the index of the terminator is the same as the number of characters in the string

Answer (score 0):

The `str` part of `strncpy` refers to the fact that it takes a string as *input*.  It doesn't always create a string as output.

My advice would be not to use it, because a lot of people who read your code will be in the same boat as you and not realize that it doesn't create a string as output.

Further, the third parameter to `strncpy` is supposed to be *the destination buffer size*.  If you are actually trying to specify a number of characters to copy, then you're conflicting with `strncpy`'s purpose because it's supposed to read a null-terminated string as input, not a number of characters.

In fact it is not even clear from your code how much memory `buffer` is pointing to.  If you've already determined `buffer` is big enough, then `strncpy` is not the right function because it exists to limit buffer overflows, but there is no danger of overflowing the buffer.

Here are two alternative approaches, where `s` is the string and you have made sure `buffer` is big enough:

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
sprintf(buffer, "%.*s", (int)len - 2, s + 1);
```

or

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
memcpy(buffer, s + 1, len - 2);
buffer[len - 2] = '\0';
```

*Note:* It would also be a smart move to check `len >= 2` before copying the characters; and the `sprintf` version is easily modifiable (by using `snprintf`) to also take the output buffer size as a parameter.